# Castle Windsor: Between multiple constructors why does Castle pick the one with incorrect argument types?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, multiple-constructors

In a scenario where a class has multiple constructors I understand that Castle Windsor has an algorithm used to detect the 'greediest' constructor and pick that one to resolve a component.

But why would a constructor be picked to start with if it doesn't match the parameter names and types specified in config.

For example, assume the following config:

```
<configuration>
<component id="MyComponent"  type="MyType"  service="IMyInterface">
  <parameters>
    <firstParam>${firstComponent}</firstParam>
    <secondParam>${secondComponent}</secondParam>
    <thirdParam>${thirdComponent}</thirdParam>
  </parameters>
</component>

<component id="MyOtherComponent"  type="MyType"  service="IMyInterface">
  <parameters>
    <firstParam>${firstComponent}</firstParam>
    <secondParam>${secondComponent}</secondParam>
    <forthParam>${forthComponent}</forthParam>
  </parameters>
</component>
```

and class MyType:

```
public class MyType : IMyInterface {

public MyType(IFirstComponent firstParam, ISecondComponent secondParam, IThirdComponent thirdParam){
    // do stuff
}

public MyType(IFirstComponent firstParam, ISecondComponent secondParam, IForthComponent forthParam){
    // do other stuff
}
```

}

What I'd expect the container to do is invoke the first constructor for MyComponent and the second constructor for MyOtherComponent. Instead, the second constructor is getting invoked for both components.

Why does Castle invoke a constructor that clearly does not match the parameter names (and types) I have specified in config?

Comment: Your class [shouldn't have multiple constructors](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97) in the first place.

Comment: Hi @Steven, I came across your article while researching this issue. Won't argue with that. But within Castle there is support for multiple constructors and there is logic in choosing the 'right' constructor. So I'll keep this question open and see if there's a proper way to address this (i.e. no workaround such as adding an extra, dummy parameter to the constructor I'd like to get invoked).

Comment: Hi, you my have a config issue. for the second constructor maybe you should use <thirdParam> instead of <forthParam>. Can you give it a try?